# Every specific weekday, sql and php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I got this:

```
SELECT `deals`.*, deals_bookings.date AS 'b_date', deals_bookings.id AS 'book_id' 
FROM `deals_bookings` 
INNER JOIN deals ON (deals.ID = deals_bookings.deal_id) 
INNER JOIN users ON (users.id = deals.partner_id) 
INNER JOIN deals_bookings_times ON (deals_bookings_times.book_id = deals_bookings.id) 
WHERE 1 AND deals_bookings.date = CURDATE() AND users.company_type = 'restaurant'
```

This grabs deals, that has a booked date for today (CURDATE()).

Now I have added a column: deals_bookings.everyWeekDay

The plan for that column is to store week number -> between 1-7 where 1 is monday (first day in week) and 7 is sunday.

Is it possible by pure mysql query to select all deals that has either deals_bookings.date = CURDATE() OR if deals_bookings.everyWeekDay = todays week number ?

Comment: If you look at the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), there are several date functions, some of which are `DAYOFWEEK()`, `DAYOFYEAR()`, and `HOUR()`.

Answer (score 1):

YOu want to use
    `deals_bookings`.`everyWeekDay` = WEEKDAY(NOW())

But WEEKDAY returns Monday - 0, Sunday - 6; so we have to add 1

Combining the condition

```
WHERE (`deals_bookings`.`date` = CURDATE() OR `deals_bookings`.`everyWeekDay` = WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 1 )  AND `users`.`company_type` = 'restaurant'
```