# Look for a number in a column with multiple numbers

Tags: mysql

Following from this:
[Every specific weekday, sql and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072017/every-specific-weekday-sql-and-php/11072092)

I got this:

```
deals_bookings.everyWeekDay = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
```

Works great if there's a single value like: 1 in it.

But `everyWeekDay` column can contain more numbers, in a format like this: `1,2,3,4`

So i would like to look for `DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())`  number in this.

How can it be done?

Comment: You normalize your database, first. Storing CSV data in a single field, when you need to access the individual members of that CSV data, basically defeats the purpose of having a relational database in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB Them's fightin' words... It's OK to denormalise, as long as you can justify it. In this case, splitting out a separate table might not be possible/desirable for various factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FIND_IN_SET(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()), deals_bookings.everyWeekDay) > 0
```